# Convert array to list in Postgres for select query

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL I am trying to convert an array to a list say I have an array: `v_arr`

I want to use this array in the below query in Postgres:

```
Select * 
from table_name 
where column_name in (v_arr)
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete source code of your function. [edit] your question do not post code in comments.

Comment: any solutions so far?

Answer (score 5):

You could use unnest

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name 
WHERE column_name IN (SELECT unnest(v_arr));
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

Comment: the above returned nothing. Its returning null Alberto

Answer (score 2):

You could use `= ANY`:

```
Select * from table_name where column_name = any (v_arr);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=ff681b9b5e59523b0b98403a437d3b0c)**

Comment: the above returned nothing. Its returning null

Comment: @StackAcc Please post your actual data.